# Plugin with id 'osgi' not found

Tags: gradle, osgi

I am trying to build a project(https://github.com/fge/btf) locally using gradle. There is a plugin "osgi" being used but whenever I build it, I get the error plugin not found. I have tried giving different flavors of OSGi, added the repositories and dependency. Still getting the same error. Please help. Thanks in advance.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/root/btf-1.2/build.gradle' line: 61
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'btf'.

  > Plugin with id 'osgi' not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

logs generated are as below

Comment: Can you add the log of the build?

Comment: Added the build logs in post.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle has discontinued their built-in `osgi` plugin. Please see the Bnd Gradle plugins.

https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md#replacing-use-of-gradles-deprecated-osgi-plugin

Comment: I added following in build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
     mavenCentral();
     jcenter();
        maven {
            url 'https://bndtools.jfrog.io/bndtools/libs-snapshot';
            url "https://repo.springsource.org/plugins-release";
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/";

        }
    }
    dependencies {

   classpath "biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.gradle:5.0.1";

}
along with
apply(plugin: "biz.aQute.bnd.builder");
This also not working and giving error

 Plugin with id 'biz.aQute.bnd.builder' not found.

Comment: `plugin { id 'biz.aQute.bnd.builder' version '5.0.1' }` should be sufficient. See https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md#using-bnd-builder-gradle-plugin